# Rewriting www.mydomain.com/index.php to www.mydomain.com

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I have found two different methods to redirect from index.php / index.html to the domain. Both seem to work; none of them ends in a loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.martin-thoma.de/terminplaner/ [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.martin-thoma.de/terminplaner/ [R=301,L]
```

edit: here is another rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://www.martin-thoma.de/terminplaner/ [R=301,L]
```

**Where is the difference between these three methods of rewriting? What should I use?**

Here is a part of the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> IS_SUBREQ Will contain the text "true"
>   if the request currently being
>   processed is a sub-request, "false"
>   otherwise. Sub-requests may be
>   generated by modules that need to
>   resolve additional files or URIs in
>   order to complete their tasks.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually redurecting and that you aren't just hitting the actual file or another rewrite rule?  I have RewriteLogLevel 9 and RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log so I can watch the logs, and it's not firing for either rule.  I'm on Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely your .htaccess in not in the `http://www.martin-thoma.de/terminplaner/` directory. So, they are working :)

Anyways, you see that, the first one is fairly simple. And, it works. For the second one, the IS_SUBREQ is always false (assuming that no other rewrite rule is translating something else to index.php or index.html. So, its working also.

[This page](http://www.colder.ch/news/01-26-2007/24/truth-about-the-last-mod_.html) will help you to understand when the IS_SUBREQ is true. This page has has example.

If you do not have any other rule, you can very safely use the first one (without RewriteCond)